# Call contract entrypoint that requires tez to be sent

Tags: taquito, transfer

I'm trying to call a `mint` entrypoint that requires tez to be sent along with the contract call. I'm not sure how I would do that and I can't find any examples.

This is the entrypoint schema:

```
"mint": {
  "issuer_address": "address",
  "issuer_id": "nat"
}
```

From what I've learned so far, my call would look something like this:

```
c.methods.mint(issuer, id)
```

I've found examples for transferring tez, but I'm not sure how to combine the transactions. Do they need to be batched?

This is my first foray into taquito and I'm a hobby dev with a lot of learning to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An amount of tez can be specified in the `send` method as follow:

```
c.methods.mint(issuer, id).send({ amount: 1 });
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!